# Was electricity ever free in Gaddafi's regime?

Tags: africa, gaddafi, libya

The internet is full of stories that Gaddafi's Libya was an Utopia. Like:

- [Is this stuff about Libya true?](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=2587289) at thestudentroom.co.uk
- [The Amazing Things Moammar Gadhafi Did For Libya](http://rense.com/general95/theam.htm) at rense.com

Could anyone confirm whether this claim about free electricity was actually true? A proof would be nice. Also, could anyone kindly verify the reports of some the other points contained in such reports.

Comment: Why do you find the claim of free electricity in a country that is an oil producer to be implausible? During oil price bubble, they could easily afford that subsidy, same way Saudi Arabia affords having their subsidies, or Alaska not having state taxes or Venezuela afforded their subsidies back then.

Comment: Also, asking "anyone from Libya" to back up the claim doesn't particularly meet the criteria of evidence for this site (unless they happen to have independent documentation).

Comment: perhaps start from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libya#Independence.2C_Kingdom_of_Libya_and_Libya_under_Gaddafi_.281951.E2.80.932011.29

Comment: Ive removed the part about "preferably from Libya" - it would be an appeal to authority.

Answer (score 8):

The claim that

> There is no electricity bill in Libya; electricity is free  for all
>   its citizens.

is **false**. There was electricity bills but the price was very low. According to [IMF](https://books.google.ch/books?id=lHkJ303fme8C&pg=PA7&dq=electricity+libya&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirubbQgpTQAhXDPI8KHQpYDgUQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=electricity%20libya&f=false), Libya's electricity price per KwH for residential consumers was 1.5 U.S. cents. (The average price people in the U.S. pay for electricity is about [12 cents](http://www.npr.org/sections/money/2011/10/27/141766341/the-price-of-electricity-in-your-state) per kilowatt-hour.)

[image: Libya electricity free]